# How to properly pass dictionary to custom operator in Apache Airflow?

Tags: python, airflow

I have created a custom operator which takes some parameters and ultimately triggers a glue job. Here's how it looks -

```py
task = MyCustomOperator(
    task_id="my_op",
    custom_property=False,
    r_params = {
        "run_date": "{{ ds }}"
    }
)
```

Inside the custom operator we use `json.dumps` on `r_params` and pass it to glue operator, which only accepts strings.

The problem is some of our DAGs are using `render_template_as_native_obj=True` so the above operator fails with an error saying expected `str` got `dict`.

My understanding is even after converting `r_params` to `str` using `json.dumps` it's still getting converted back to `dict` after rendering `{{ ds }}`.

What's the correct way to pass dict to a custom operator so that it doesn't clash with the native object property?

Answer (score 0):

You can get `params` using `Context`. As well as other task variables. Here is an example `test.py`:

```
import datetime
import logging
from typing import Any

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.models import BaseOperator
from airflow.utils.context import Context


class DarkMatterOperator(BaseOperator):
    def execute(self, context: Context) -> Any:
        logging.info('Context variables')
        for key in context.keys():
            logging.info('%s = %s', key, context[key])


dag = DAG(
     dag_id='demo',
     start_date=datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 1),
     schedule=None,
)


DarkMatterOperator(
    params={'some_value': '1'},
    dag=dag,
    task_id='DarkMatterOperator1',
)


DarkMatterOperator(
    params={'some_new_value': '2'},
    dag=dag,
    task_id='DarkMatterOperator2',
)
```

Let's run and check `DarkMatterOperator1` logs:

```
[2024-02-27, 21:18:47 UTC] {test.py:12} INFO - Context variables
[2024-02-27, 21:18:47 UTC] {test.py:14} INFO - conf = <airflow.configuration.AirflowConfigParser object at 0x7fe0da8e4970>
[2024-02-27, 21:18:47 UTC] {test.py:14} INFO - dag = <DAG: demo>
[2024-02-27, 21:18:47 UTC] {test.py:14} INFO - dag_run = <DagRun demo @ 2024-02-27 21:18:44.404291+00:00: manual__2024-02-27T21:18:44.404291+00:00, state:running, queued_at: 2024-02-27 21:18:44.413595+00:00. externally triggered: True>
[2024-02-27, 21:18:47 UTC] {test.py:14} INFO - data_interval_end = 2024-02-27T21:18:44.404291+00:00
[2024-02-27, 21:18:47 UTC] {test.py:14} INFO - data_interval_start = 2024-02-27T21:18:44.404291+00:00
[2024-02-27, 21:18:47 UTC] {test.py:14} INFO - ds = 2024-02-27
[2024-02-27, 21:18:47 UTC] {test.py:14} INFO - execution_date = 2024-02-27T21:18:44.404291+00:00
[2024-02-27, 21:18:47 UTC] {test.py:14} INFO - expanded_ti_count = None
[2024-02-27, 21:18:47 UTC] {test.py:14} INFO - inlets = []
[2024-02-27, 21:18:47 UTC] {test.py:14} INFO - logical_date = 2024-02-27T21:18:44.404291+00:00
[2024-02-27, 21:18:47 UTC] {test.py:14} INFO - next_execution_date = 2024-02-27T21:18:44.404291+00:00
[2024-02-27, 21:18:47 UTC] {test.py:14} INFO - outlets = []
[2024-02-27, 21:18:47 UTC] {test.py:14} INFO - params = {'some_value': '1'}                              <-  your params
[2024-02-27, 21:18:47 UTC] {test.py:14} INFO - prev_data_interval_start_success = 2024-02-27T21:11:13.093336+00:00
[2024-02-27, 21:18:47 UTC] {test.py:14} INFO - prev_data_interval_end_success = 2024-02-27T21:11:13.093336+00:00
[2024-02-27, 21:18:47 UTC] {test.py:14} INFO - prev_execution_date_success = 2024-02-27T21:11:13.093336+00:00
[2024-02-27, 21:18:47 UTC] {test.py:14} INFO - prev_start_date_success = 2024-02-27T21:11:14.277766+00:00
[2024-02-27, 21:18:47 UTC] {test.py:14} INFO - run_id = manual__2024-02-27T21:18:44.404291+00:00
[2024-02-27, 21:18:47 UTC] {test.py:14} INFO - task = <Task(DarkMatterOperator): DarkMatterOperator1>
[2024-02-27, 21:18:47 UTC] {test.py:14} INFO - task_instance = <TaskInstance: demo.DarkMatterOperator1 manual__2024-02-27T21:18:44.404291+00:00 [running]>
[2024-02-27, 21:18:47 UTC] {test.py:14} INFO - task_instance_key_str = demo__DarkMatterOperator1__20240227
[2024-02-27, 21:18:47 UTC] {test.py:14} INFO - test_mode = False
[2024-02-27, 21:18:47 UTC] {test.py:14} INFO - ti = <TaskInstance: demo.DarkMatterOperator1 manual__2024-02-27T21:18:44.404291+00:00 [running]>
[2024-02-27, 21:18:47 UTC] {test.py:14} INFO - ts = 2024-02-27T21:18:44.404291+00:00
....
```

Let's check `DarkMatterOperator2` log:

```
...
[2024-02-27, 21:18:50 UTC] {test.py:14} INFO - params = {'some_new_value': '2'}     <- your params
...
```

So just use `Context` and implement the `execute` method